# How to diagnose AWS API Gateway errors when there is no logging client-side

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I created an API with AWS API Gateway. This API provides a method that calls an AWS Lambda function. When I call this API method manually using a REST client, it works properly, and the Lambda function is called.

I also have a device that periodically pushes some data to a server via HTTP(S). When configured to push data to a HTTPS server running on an EC2 instance, it works properly. But when I configure the device to push data to API Gateway, the Lambda function is never called.

I tried sniffing the traffic via WireShark, and I can see that requests are indeed sent by the device and that the API responds, but I can't view the contents of the requests and responses since they are encrypted. My guess is that API Gateway returns somme kind of error that prevents the Lambda to be called. Unfortunately, the device does not provide any logs. Is there any way on AWS side to see what is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable CloudWatch Logs for API Gateway: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudwatch-logs/

Comment: Thank You. I followed the instructions, and now hundreds of log streams are generated in CloudWatch for my API, but they are all empty. I am searching how to solve this now.

Comment: I solved this by deleting my API then deploying it again.